# How to check if surrounding buttons are disabled

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an onscreen keyboard, if a user mistakenly types the wrong letter and presses backspace that letter/button is disabled.

I want to make it that if three buttons are pressed and deleted surrounding one button, it should make the inside button be pressed. This should only happen if the button is surrounded on three sides by mistake buttons.

1) The Size of the buttons change so I can't check with buttons locations

2) I can manually type in every possible combination, but I wanted to know if there is a quicker, and more concise way to write this?

Comment: Can't you make a grid with buttons? Checking left, up, right and down button from pressed one?

Comment: At times the size of the buttons and location change and move will this be messed up in a grid?

Comment: Does the size of the buttons change or the actual locations as well?

Comment: both, and some buttons (like space) take two boxes so wouldn't be an even grid

Comment: Why aren't you using the default windows on-screen keyboard function? With: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe")

Comment: because its in a different language, and used on an eye-tracking device

Comment: I don't see how we can help without seeing some pictures since you say the layout is changing.  Unless they are in some kind of grid, like a TableLayoutPanel, I don't see a way of doing this without using their current size/location.  We need more info on the layout...

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to have a link on each button to each of its neighbors. Left and right will be easy to initialize, but you may need to initialize vertical neighbors "manually" because of special cases. At run time, just use the links to check buttons.

Comment: One way is to use an array or list of buttons, then use integer links to the array subscripts.